# Selecting a Link on the Reputation Page Expands/Collapses the List

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-tab

There has been a recent change in the user interface that I think is buggy.

When selecting a link on [someone's reputation page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=post), not only does it navigate to the post selected, but it also expands/collapses the list of reputation actions for that post.

If one is simply clicking, they are sent to the selected post. The expansion/collapse of the list is just noise before the page change.

If one is shift-clicking (at least in Firefox), the selected post is opened in a new window after the list is expanded/collapsed on the reputation page. There is no way to go to the linked post without expanding/collapsing the list any more.

For me, if I want to expand/collapse the list, I would rather do it using the triangle to the left, as was intended for that UI element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour change is a result of implementing [Fix UI of the Reputation Tab Rows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238190/13). Unfortunately, it seems you're in the "only the triangle should activate expansion" camp, and the other ticket's OP is in the "clicking anywhere in the row should activate expansion" camp.

Our [Markdown help](/editing-help)'s expandable sections also expand when clicking on the title, not just the arrow. I would say that the latter behaviour is, thus, more consistent.

However, I take your point that clicking an outbound link would, ideally, not trigger the expansion. I'll see if that can be done, but the rest of the row should still do the expansion.

---

I've fixed this by calling `stopPropagation` when clicking on question and answer links. This worked for me when tested on Chrome. It will be deployed in build 2883, but, since this is somewhat of an annoyance, I'll deploy it in the next 10 minutes.

Comment: Build 2883 has landed. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for acting on this so quickly! Indeed, I do believe that the expansion/collapse should only be triggered by the triangle, but this is much better than not being able to separate the actions.